# Se repite impresion en Script SAP

Tags: excel, vba, script

Estoy trabajando con una macro, la cual me imprime las guias de despacho. Lo hace correctamente, pero cuando voy a imprimir una seguida de otra, se me repite la primera.
Vean en la imagen que se me repitieron las sucursales Llanquihue y Osorno.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Añadí un set a la variable que guarda la sucursal, pero no se soluciona

```
Sub creadorGD()

Dim application
Dim connection
Dim userID
Dim GridView As Object

Set objsheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set sucursal = Range("C7")
Call limpia

H = Range("B7")
sucursal = Range("C7")
```

Espero me puedan ayudar.
Gracias como siempre

Saludos

Comment: ¿Puede ser que las repita porque el valor de `Entrega`es diferente a pesar de ser la misma sucursal?

Comment: Hola @ElierSánchezE-Infantes
No. el campo Entrega ,,, clase de entrega es estático, independiente de cada sucursal. 
lo que hice ayer fue tambien añadir un Set a "H", que es el rango en donde se encuentra la lista de validacion de datos.
Voy a ver como me va con eso hoy.
Gracias por tu comentario

Comment: Creo que sería mejor si pusieras el input de tus datos y el output. Pon de donde partes inicialmente y a donde quieres llegar. El código que has puesto no hace nada. Solamente asigna variables y nada más